# Class object not working as expected. Do I need to add arguments to class object?

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to wrap my head around Python classes. My script is trying to create a class that determines commission pay, pre-tax and after-tax. The class work for pre-tax but I'm getting issues for after-tax.

```
class Commission():
    def __init__(self, call, permit, install):
        self.call = call
        self.permit = permit
        self.install = install
    
    def pay_pre_tax(self):
        calls = 300
        permits = 200
        installs = 500
        total = calls * self.call + permits * self.permit + installs + self.install
        return total

    def taxes(self):
        tax_rate = 4.66 / total
        return tax_rate

    def total_pay(self):
        total = self.pay_pre_tax()
        total_pay = total + tax_rate
        return total_pay

Pynchon = Commission(1, 2, 3)

print(Pynchon.pay_pre_tax())
Pynchon.taxes()
print(Pynchon.total_pay())
```

I get an errors for "Pynchon.taxes()"--> "NameError: name 'total' is not defined" and "NameError: name 'tax_rate' is not defined"

Would I have to somehow add total to the argument in Commission for this to work properly?

Comment: When you create an instance of `Commission` its `__init__()` method creates three attributes. You can reference them in any of the method by prepending `self.` to them. If one of your other methods creates a new attribute, like `self.total`, from then on the same thing applies.

Comment: I suppose I'm confused how you would use, say, "tax_rate" from one function in another without causing an issue?

Comment: If you assigned a value to `self.tax_rate` in one method, you can access it in another the same way. If you don't add the `self.` and assign a value to a name like plain `tax_rate`, it will cause a local variable to be created that can only be referenced within that method. You can, of course, always return values from methods (or functions) to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all the variables you created inside methods(viz. totall, tax rate etc) does not belong to the object but its scope is limited to the methods in which it is initialized. The following code might work properly :

```
class Commission:
    def __init__(self, call, permit, install):
        self.call = call
        self.permit = permit
        self.install = install
    
    def pay_pre_tax(self):
        calls = 300
        permits = 200
        installs = 500
        self.total = calls * self.call + permits * self.permit + installs + self.install
        return self.total

    def taxes(self):
        self.tax_rate = 4.66 / self.total
        return self.tax_rate

    def total_pay(self):
        total = self.pay_pre_tax()
        total_pay = total + self.tax_rate
        return total_pay

Pynchon = Commission(1, 2, 3)

print(Pynchon.pay_pre_tax())
Pynchon.taxes()
print(Pynchon.total_pay())
```